# UWP file storage where user cannot access

Tags: c#, file, uwp, storagefile

I am developing a library for UWP apps,
I want to store some data.
Is it possible to create, read and write to a file where user can't access.

`Windows.Storage.ApplicationData` folders can be accessible by user.

I want to store information where user can not access .
Thanks in advance.
Noorul.

Answer (score 1):

Files that can never be accessed do not exist. What we can do is "hidden files" in most cases.

Usually, you can safely store data in `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`. Its corresponding folder is hidden in the file explorer, most users will not open it.

If you need to protect the information in the file, you can try to encrypt the file, such as using `Base64` to convert the text inside the file, so that users can not directly read the content.

If you need access to information about encryption, this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/cryptography) may help you.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to prevent a user from accessing their own files.
There are ways to prevent a user from reading their full control files.
What is your use?